# Call to database after successful login is not being made

Tags: vue.js

I'm having difficulty in getting an axios call to my database being initiated after a user has logged into my SPA.

1. A route (gaplist/3) brings the user to a page (gaplist.vue) which
   detects if the user is logged in or not.
2. If not logged in, a login form is presented.
3. Once the entered username/password combo is accepted, the user is "pushed" to the same page (gaplist/3)
4. Here, the logged in status is detected and - this is where it all falls down - a call to the database would return a bunch of records associated with the user and the parameter "3".

Unfortunately, the last step doesn't fully happen. The logged in status is detected, but the database call is not made. Only if I refresh the page is the call made and the results presented.

What concept am I not grasping here?

Thanks, Tom.

My code is as follows:

GapList.vue (route: gaplist/3)

```
<template>
  <v-content>
    <v-container fluid fill-height>
      <v-layout justify-center>
        <v-flex xs12 sm6>
          <h1>Production and sale of produce</h1>
          <v-card flat>
            <div v-if="isIn">
              <p v-for="(card, id) in cards">{{card.product}}</p>
              <logout-button></logout-button>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
              <gap-login :gapid=gapid></gap-login>
            </div>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
</template>

<script>
  import GapLogin from '../components/gap/GapLogin';
  import LogoutButton from '../components/gap/LogoutButton'

  export default {
    name: 'GapList',
    components: {
      GapLogin,
      LogoutButton
    },
    data () {
      return {
        gapid: this.$route.params.id,
        cards: [],
        lang: this.$i18n.locale,
        bNoRecords: false,
      }
    },
    created(){
      this.loadCrops(this.gapid,this.lang)
    },    
    computed: {
      isIn : function(){ return this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn},
    },
    methods: {
      loadCrops(gapid,lang){
        var vm = this;
        if (this.isIn){
          axios.get('/gapcroplist/' + gapid)
          .then(function (resp) {
            vm.cards = resp.data;
          })
          .catch(function (resp) {
            vm.bNoRecords = true;
          });
        }
      },
    }
  }
</script>
```

GapLogin.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="formdiv">
      <v-layout justify-center>
          <h3>Login</h3>
          <v-card flat>
            <v-alert
                v-if="loginError"
                :value="true"
                type="error"
                transition="scale-transition"
                dismissible
            >
              You didn't enter correct information
            </v-alert>
            <v-form class="login" @submit.prevent="login">
              <v-text-field
                v-model="form.email"
                type="email"
                label="Email"
                required
                autofocus
              ></v-text-field>
              <v-text-field
                v-model="form.password"
                type="password"
                label="Password"
                required
              ></v-text-field>
              <v-btn
                  type="submit"
              >Login in </v-btn>
            </v-form>
          </v-card>
      </v-layout>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "GapLogin",
    props: ['gapid'],
    data() {
      return {
        form: {
          email: null,
          password: null
        },
        loginError:false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      login: function () {
        this.loginError = false
        this.$store.dispatch('login', this.form)
          .then(() =>
          {this.$router.push({path: '/gaplist/' + this.gapid})
          })
          .catch(err => {
            this.loginError = true
          }
      )
      },
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: What does your network tab in DevTools tell you?

Comment: are you sure `gapId` is passed along correctly?

Comment: gapId is being passed along correctly (a series of console.logs and {{gapId}} show this).  The network tab shows no triggering of the method at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

`created` hook will not be called again. Using `updated` will result in an error as well, as you would trigger another update and have an endless loop.

Instead of pushing to same route I would suggest that you emit a `completed` event:

In your `login` method in `then` instead of `$router.push`:

```
this.$emit('completed')
```

And register the event on the `gap-login`-component:

```
<gap-login @completed="completed" :gapid=gapid></gap-login>
```

And add that method to the `GapList.vue`-file:

```
completed () {
  this.loadCrops(this.gapid, this.lang)
}
```

---

You are using `axios` in a global context, but it doesn't exists, it seems.

Try using `this.$axios`:

```
this.$axios.get('/gapcroplist/' + gapid)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this change didn't solve the problem. After further playing, I've discovered that loadCrops isn't being called after the login stage. If I change the hook from created to 'beforeUpdate' or 'updated', it does get called but is called again and again and again... so neither is a solution.  Changing the hook to 'mounted' doesn't result in loadCrops being called.

Comment: More specifically, the 'this.$axios...' option yields the error "Error in updated hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Comment: Oh yes, I see a problem now. You're calling `loadCrops` on created. `created` is only called when the component is .. well, created. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Excellent!. Thanks - I'd seen $emit in the past but there is nothing like a worked example on your own code to make the penny drop.